# Close a cycle in a TikZ graph with a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

Consider the following simple flow diagram. I like using the graph drawing library in TikZ for its simplicity and semantics:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
    \usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

    \tikz[>=latex]
        \graph[
            tree layout,
            node pre sep = 0.2em,
            grow=right,
            },
        ]
        {
            A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> (A.south)
        };

\end{document}
```

This code connects an arrow from `E.west` to `A.south` that crosses the other nodes. How can I create a loop that leaves `E.south` or `E.east` and then goes downwards to enter `A.south` or maybe `A.west` in the end again?

Comment: The code does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\graph[
  tree layout,
  node pre sep = 0.2em,
  grow=right,
  ]
  {
    A -> B -> C -> D -> E ->[bend left] A
  };
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\graph[
  tree layout,
  node pre sep = 0.2em,
  grow=right,
  ]
  {
    A -> B -> C -> D -> E ->[out=-90,in=-90] A
  };
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\graph[
  tree layout,
  node pre sep = 0.2em,
  grow=right,
  ]
  {[name=str]
    A -> B -> C -> D -> E 
  };
  \draw[-] (str E.east) to[out=0,in=0] ([yshift=-15pt]str C);
  \draw[<-] (str A.west) to[out=180,in=180] ([yshift=-15pt]str C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first two options use the fact that you can use the `->[...]` syntax to modify the path; the third option uses the `[name=<string>]` prefix for the graph nodes and then two appropriate `\draw` commands.